# Can Flutter iOS builds be sped up on Github Actions?

Tags: ios, flutter, github-actions

I'm trying to distribute an iOS app on Github Actions that was made with Flutter.

The whole process takes 12 minutes to do the archive before distribution. The project is just for the template Flutter project you get when you create a new project. There's no other bits of code.

There are three areas that take a non-trivial amount of time:

Running `subosito/flutter-action@v1` takes just over 1 minute.

Running `flutter build ipa --flavor MyAppStaging --release --export-options-plist=.github/stagingExportOptions.plist` takes about 10 minutes

Running `actions/upload-artifact@master` takes about 1 minute.

Is there some sort of optimisation that I can do?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that 12 minutes of build/release time is unacceptable for your use case? I know thousands of projects that would consider such a timeframe to be excellent.

Comment: Yeah, my boss doesn't believe me that it should take this long.

Comment: Even if it *shouldnt* take that long, what is the use case for having it be any faster? What is the benefit of being able to build a release package in, say, 3 minutes, as opposed to 12? I don’t know of any iOS app that deploys continuously enough to gain any benefit from such an optimization.

Comment: Fair point. It seems to be more of a cost reduction concern by the boss.

Comment: @esqew whether 12 minutes is long or not, the question is still valid and very much in need of an answer. It's 2023, I've been investigating for 3 days and still no good answer (many others stuck on the same boat as far as I have seen). Also Github Actions cost money, server minutes are expensive.